# Will playing The Walking Dead spoil the comics?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I haven't read the Walking Dead comics yet. Would playing the games by Telltale give away much, or do they have a different storyline?

Comment: While I feel your pain, I'm voting to close this as 'non constructive'.  This question just feels too subjective to me; what 'ruins' it for one person might not bother another at all.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I'm unconvinced. All he's asking is if the plotline of the games is the same as that of the comics, which, as Emerica demonstrates, is answerable in a non-subjective way.

Comment: @Mana Re-read and thought about it for a bit, and I think you're right.

Comment: Edited the question to make it sound less subjective, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a completley new storyline. You can read from [this link](http://www.pcworld.com/article/254797/why_you_should_play_the_walking_dead_episode_one.html)-

> ...a game spanning five monthly episodes that tells a **new** story in the Walking Dead universe while staying true to the grim tone of the comic books.

Also, if you haven't read the comics yet, you really should they are amazing. The show is really good too, but it doesn't follow the comics all that well so far.

Answer (score 1):

No - the only character from the comics who appears in the game is Glenn, and his appearance in the game takes place before the comics and tv show